# Search an element from user in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, search

I have a task to make a search option where I have to find an input from keyboard, let's say a series of numbers. After I find it, I have to look through the whole .xml element, edit one part of it and finally put it in a *.txt* file.

```
<data>
    <art>< name="blah", code="0356", instock="03"></art>
    <art>< name="blah2", code="0523", instock="10"></art>
</data>
```

So, you should write an number to search in an xml, then change the value of "instock" with a number that you want, and after you change it, put it in txt. But only that one. All numbers (code that I search for and instock value that should be added) have to be entered via keyboard. Which is the main problem here.

To be honest I have no idea how to do it I have tried everything and nothing works. It only pops errors.

Comment: Explain a bit more. What is the input? do you always want to update `instock` element?

Comment: The question is really vague. Would be great if you can be more specific

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow!
I edited your question for clarity of intent, as well as punctuation. This makes reading the question easier for people who may answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement art = doc.Descendants("art").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("code") == "0356").FirstOrDefault();
            art.SetAttributeValue("instock", "456");

            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```